# Vlookup with more than one same value

Tags: vlookup

I am trying to do a vlookup but my table array has more than one same value, and the result is only the first cell,

So, I would like to know how can I do to improve this function,

I'll explain the image, as you can see my table array is 251724001-4799 and what I am looking is the table called FED_INDICED and they have 7 differents values however my vlookup only throws me one

The next example has my inquiry

[image]

Comment: Would you like to share your vlookup code??

Answer (score 0):

A simple vlookup function doesn't return multiple values. You would have to write an Index function. In this case I would recommend to do it horizontally. You would need a function similar to this one here:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$9, SMALL(IF($A$11=$A$2:$A$9, ROW($A$2:$A$9)-ROW($A$2)+1), COLUMN(A1)))
```